# C on a Mac: trying to use 'open' does not actually open the url

Tags: c

I'm working through chapter 10 of Head First C, and I've come to this program which is supposed to read an RSS feed for my search term and then open the URL for each term. The book is a little vague on how the open_url function it had me write works exactly, but from what I can tell from the man page of 'open', I think it should be opening in either Safari or my default browser. Only problem is, nothing happens. The code compiles beautifully and runs with no issue except that it just doesn't open the web pages even when I use a search term I know should return something. How do I begin troubleshooting something like this when I don't even get any errors to go off of?

```
void open_url(char *url)
{
  char launch[255];
  sprintf(launch, "open '%s'", url);
  system(launch);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *phrase = argv[1];
  char *vars[] = {"RSS_FEED=https://www.npr.org/rss/podcast.php?id=510298", NULL};

  ...

  char line[255];
  while (fgets(line, 255, stdin)){
    if (line[0] == '\t')
      open_url(line + 1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, your code is not *minimal*. For a minimal example, the contents of `main` would be one line, e.g. `open_url("https://www.google.com");`

Comment: Try printing the url when you receive it in `open_url` function. See if it's a valid url. And you should test if it opens pages like "https://www.google.com" in the first place to see if there's any error with your urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Mac, this MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) opens the Google main search page in a new tab of an already running default browser (it happens to be Firefox).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void open_url(const char *url)
{
    char launch[255];
    snprintf(launch, sizeof(launch), "open '%s'", url);
    system(launch);
}

int main(void)
{
    open_url("https://www.google.com/");
    return 0;
}
```

The code doesn't ensure that the URL is not truncated (but it does ensure there is no overflow); it should be fixed.

You need to experiment now.

- Does this code work for you?
- If so, you need to find out what's different between this and your non-operational code.
- If not, you can start diagnosing from this.

  - Is the browser already running?
  - If not, does it work when the browser is running?

When I add a newline at the end of the URL string, I get a failure (the URL is presented as `https://www.google.com/%0A` and I get a 404 error, but the browser does respond to the `open` command).  However, your code using `fgets()` should probably use something equivalent to this:

```
line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = '\0';
```

to remove line endings in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the formatting, I've edited the post. Your code works and is helpful, and in trying to get it to work within my original code, it led me to realize that something is going wrong with the python script that pulls from the RSS feed - it seems to be pulling titles, not URLs, which is why nothing really happens. I'll need to fix that first.